# Ошибка при выполнении кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал код, который должен переделывать строку "Я есть Грут. Ты нет." в "Грут есть я. Нет ты."

```py
sentance = input().split('.')

first = []
second =[]

for word in sentance[0].split():
    word = word.strip('.')
    first.append(word)
    
for word in sentance[1].split():
    word = word.strip('.')
    second.append(word)

first = first.reverse()
second = second.reverse()

for i in first, second:
    i[-1] = i[-1] + '.'
    i[0] = i[0].title()    

print(*first, *second)
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    i[-1] = i[-1] + '.'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Замените метод reverse на функцию reversed (и тогда всё работает так, как вы хотите):

```
first = list(reversed(first))
second = list(reversed(second))
```

В описании метода сказано, что он ничего не возвращает. А функция - возвращает. На это и ошибка указывала - NoneType часто в таких случаях получаем.

Comment: Я так уже у себя сделал. Оно работает в юпитере и pycarm, но вот в яндекс.контест нет

Comment: Тогда ставьте правильно задачу изначально - в рамках ТЗ все исправлено:-) Принимайте работу:-)))
Что такое яндекс.контест, а тем более, какая там у вас ошибка (раз вы не пишете её), я ведать не ведаю:-)
Но если в PyCharm работает, то вряд ли проблема в самом коде Python. Рекомендую открыть другой запрос с этим конкретным вопросом.

Comment: Полез интереса ради в яндекс.контест - не пускает меня, там ещё и регистрация нужна. Но учтите, например, что даже IDLE не всегда правильно работатет (например, print не работает в многопроцессном режиме), ничего с этим не сделать, кроме того, как уйти в PyCharm. Так что как наш домашний Яндекс их Python обрабатывает - большой вопрос:-) Я бы посмотрел на официально озвученные отличия яндекс.контекст и, если ничего не видно, то спросил их техподдержку, сославшись на историю с IDLE.

Comment: И на всякий случай, правильно писать по-русски "ты - нет" (с тире). Может ли ругаться на это Яндекс - не знаю. Проверьте на всякий случай.

Comment: @Sd1g, помогло что-то, работает теперь? Если да, в чём дело было? И предлагаю тогда принять ответ наиболее подходящий, поставить плюсы через треугольники, там где ответы полезны были.

Answer (score 1):

```
sentance = input().split('.')

first = []
second = []

for word in sentance[0].split():
    word = word.strip('.')
    first.append(word)
    
for word in sentance[1].split():
    word = word.strip('.')
    second.append(word)

first.reverse()
second.reverse()

for i in first, second:
    i[-1] = i[-1] + '.'
    i[0] = i[0].title()    

print(*first, *second)
```

Так возможно заработает

Comment: Плюс-то я поставил:-), но вот за счет чего заработать должно? Чем reverse лучше reversed?